# Is There Any Reason to Use Selectors in Swift?

Tags: swift, selector

Specifically, when a task can be complemented with or without selectors, is there any (objective) reason to prefer one way over the other?

For instance, an NSTimer can run a method on an interval in two ways:

A) Using Selectors:

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction()), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

dynamic func timerAction() {
    print("foo")    
}
```

B) Without Selectors:

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
    self.timerAction()
}

func timerAction() {
    print("foo")
}
```

Both versions are entirely functional, so is there any (objective) reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: The block version is an iOS10+ method only for your case. If you target iOS9, you can't use it.

Comment: @Larme Interesting. Both work on macOS 10.12, but I can't speak to anything earlier.

Comment: @BrandonBradley Simply look at the documentation. The block version of `Timer.scheduledTimer` was added in macOS 10.12 and iOS 10.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The target/selector design is baggage left over from the earlier Objective-C, pre-block days of the APIs.

If Apple were to redo all of those APIs today, the whole target/selector design would disappear and all be replaced with blocks/closures. This idea is supported by newer Apple APIs. Example - the old `UIAlertView` used a delegate. The newer `UIAlertController` only uses closures/blocks for the alert actions.

Using closures (Swift) or blocks (Objective-C) is much preferred over using the target/selector approach.

Here are problems with using target/selector:

1. The dreaded "unrecognized selector" error.
2. The need to create an extra, top-level method just for the selector.
3. The possibility of specifying the wrong parameters and data types on the selector method.
4. Losing all of the current context you have at the point you setup the object that needs the target/selector.

The opposite of all of those are the benefits of using the closure/block form.

It's possible, that over time, many of the delegate versions of APIs will become deprecated and replaced with closure/block versions. If you have the choice, I'd suggest using the closure/block form now to avoid the need to update later, not to mention it's just the simpler solution.